# Appcelerator Titanium - auto height table views break with shortish text

Tags: iphone, uitableview, titanium, appcelerator

I [posted this on the Appcelerator Titanium dev Q&A site](http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/8981/auto-height-table-views-break-with-shortish-text), but maybe someone here has had this issue...

KitchenSink 1.1 illustrates this issue. In `table_view_api_auto_height.js`, changing row:

`addRow(0,'This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.  This is some long text.');`

to something like:

`addRow(0,'This is some long text.  This is some long text.');`

results in incorrect left padding on the row. See screenshot:

[screenshot http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/7987/screenshot20100329at244.png](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/7987/screenshot20100329at244.png)

Answer (score 0):

try textAlign: "left"; on your row declaration. This should at a minimum, ensure the text is aligned to the left of the row. If this does not solve the issue assign a width property to the row. That should fix it.